# iphone App : while dissmissing the modelView button image rotates at 90 degree

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

in my iPhone App

when i capturing an image and show it in button at that time all thing works fine.
 After going to the next screen when i cme back to the original screen button image will rotate.

When i dissmiss the modelview and come to the original view button image rotate to  90 degree.Please guide me.

```
     my code in view will appear:

     NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     
      NSUserDomainMask, YES);

       NSString *newPath=[[path objectAtIndex:0]        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bg5.png"];

    [btnUserImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:newPath] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Hi can you post a screenshot of what exactly happens? As we are not able to make out the exact situation.

Comment: The first time when you set the button image, do you directly load it from the captured image object or from the documents directory file path where you have saved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this code will help you..

if you have problem of rotation image then check the image orientation and rotate it like this..

```
 if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationRight)
        {

            imgview.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);



        }

        else{

            imgview.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2 );


        }
```